# Gamblers ruin, parallel compute trials

Tags: python, statistics, simulation, multiprocessing

**Context**

The following script is a quick implementation of the gambler's ruin problem. For each given upper bound on the number of rounds in a game `max_iter`, simulate several games (trials) in parallel and summarize statistics.

**Question**

Is there a more efficient/neater way to parallelize? For example, the main method `simulate_game` only takes in one input parameter for convenience when calling `Pool` and it'd be nice to instead have e.g. `simulate_game(max_iter, args)`.

```
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from random import random as unif_rand

def simulate_game(max_iter):
    """Gambler wins/loses with prob 0.5 and the game stops when either:
        i) the gambler runs out of money, or
        ii) house runs out of money, or
        iii) max_iter reached.

    Params:
        max_iter (int): upper bound on number of rounds in game.

    Returns:
        curr_iter (int): num iterations reached at end of game.

    Notes:
        "game" is synonymous with "trial".
    """
    # hardcoded vals to make parallelization easier...
    gambler_limit=100
    house_limit=200
    gambler_win_prob=0.5
    curr_iter = 0
    # simulate game
    while gambler_limit and house_limit and curr_iter < max_iter:
        curr_iter += 1
        u = unif_rand()
        payout = 1 if u > gambler_win_prob else -1
        gambler_limit += payout
        house_limit += -payout
    return curr_iter

class GamblerStats(object):
    """Compute and record stats."""

    def __init__(self, avg_duration_list=[], var_duration_list=[]):
        self.avg_duration_list = avg_duration_list
        self.var_duration_list = var_duration_list

    def compute_duration_stats(self, duration_list):
        self.avg_duration = np.mean(duration_list)
        self.var_duration = np.var(duration_list)
        return None

    def update_stats(self, duration_list):
        """Update stats based on new duration_list."""
        self.compute_duration_stats(duration_list)
        self.avg_duration_list.append(self.avg_duration)
        self.var_duration_list.append(self.var_duration)
        return None

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start_time = time.time()
    procs = 3  # num physical cores - 1
    max_range = 20
    scale_iter = 2e4
    max_iter_list = [n*scale_iter for n in range(1, max_range)]  # max iter per trial
    n_trials = 250  # num trials per experiment
    # Execute Simulated Experiments
    gambler_stats = GamblerStats()
    for max_iter in max_iter_list:
        # parallel compute trials
        jobs = [max_iter] * n_trials
        duration_list = Pool(procs).map(simulate_game, jobs)
        # Update Gambler Stats
        gambler_stats.update_stats(duration_list)
    # Summarize Time
    end_time = time.time()
    work_time = end_time - start_time
    print('Time taken for all simulations', work_time)
    # Example Plot
    plt.title('Avg Game Duration [iter]')
    plt.xlabel('max_iter x {:.0E}'.format(scale_iter))
    plt.ylabel('Avg Duration')
    plt.plot(gambler_stats.avg_duration_list, '.-')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Assigning number of processors

You currently set `procs = 3`, specifically for your 4-core machine. You can get the number of (logical) cores of your machine using the [`multiprocessing.cpu_count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.cpu_count) function:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
procs = cpu_count() - 1
```

## Create `Pool` just once

Rather than creating a new `Pool` every iteration of your for-loop, it is better to just create it once and keep using the same one. By using the `with` statement, it also makes sure to close it all neatly when you're done with it.

```py
with Pool(procs) as p:
    for max_iter in max_iter_list:
        jobs = [max_iter] * n_trials
        duration_list = p.map(simulate_game, jobs)
        gambler_stats.update_stats(duration_list)
```

## Hardcoded values in `simulate_games` function

First of all, you can define your default values in the function definition. This also makes the difference more clear between the hardcoded defaults and initializations like `cur_iter = 0`

```py
def simulate_game(max_iter, 
                  gambler_limit=100, 
                  house_limit=200, 
                  gambler_win_prob=0.5):
```

### Create different fixed-value alternative using `partial`

To have a fixed different set of default values, you could use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
simulate_high_roller = partial(simulate_game, gambler_limit=1_000)
with Pool(procs) as p:
    duration_list = p.map(simulate_high_roller , jobs)
```

### Mapping with multiple arguments: `starmap`

If instead you want to simulate using a whole range of parameter values, [`Pool.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap) is probably what you're looking for. Just like the 'regular' [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), it allows you to pass in a list of tuples that it will unpack and pass to your function.

So if you have pre-defined lists of parameters you want to simulate, you can use `zip` to create the tuples.

```py
# Example
max_iter_list = [10, 20, 50]
gambler_limits = [50, 100, 200]
house_limits = [150, 200, 250]
win_probabilities = [0.6, 0.5, 0.4]

with Pool(procs) as p:
    for arguments in zip(max_iter_list, gambler_limits, house_limits, win_probabilities):
        jobs = [arguments] * n_trials
        duration_list = p.starmap(simulate_game, jobs)
```

In case of a full grid-search of your parameters, this combines nicely with [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), although that set of combinations will grow quite fast, so be deliberate about which ones you need to test.

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> arguments = list(product(max_iter_list, gambler_limits, 
...                          house_limits, win_probabilities))
>>> print(arguments)
[(10, 50, 150, 0.6),
 (10, 50, 150, 0.5),
 (10, 50, 150, 0.4),
 (10, 50, 200, 0.6),
 ...
 (50, 200, 200, 0.4),
 (50, 200, 250, 0.6),
 (50, 200, 250, 0.5),
 (50, 200, 250, 0.4)]
>>> len(arguments)
81
```

Comment: thank you! one brief follow-up, creating an instance of Pool 'just once' definitely looks cleaner, but is it also 'safer' somehow wrt to threading as compared with creating a new instance under a loop?

Comment: @Quetzalcoatl That I don't know, I'm not too aware of different threading options and backends, I just know this one works :')